# Android on tablet meta viewport initial-scale doesn't seem to work at all

Tags: android, html, mobile, viewport, meta-tags

Whenever I try to do anything with `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=xxx">`, tablets using Android freak out and does things I can't comprehend. I already know that this is because Android doesn't follow the meta viewport W3 specs, but is there a crossplatform workaround? Is there a way to define maximum-scale in terms of pixels? Tablets on Android don't seem to acknowledge setting the width of the page at all.

Works for iOS & Android phone, but breaks on Android tablet: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=maximum-scale">`

Works for tablets, but breaks on mobile (regardless of OS) `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I should just remove the initial-scale and let the device figure out how much it should scale. I was originally having problems with iOS zooming in too far when I didn't specify initial-scale, but all I had to do was set the content-width to be larger than the page's actual content's width.